# Integrate complains about incompatible quantities in integration limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, units

When I run the following code, `Integrate` throws `Missing or incompatible quantities encountered in integration limits {x, xdummy, 10 m}`. Yet the `Plot` runs successfully.

```
result = Integrate[Quantity[3, "kN/m"] (1 - x/Quantity[10, "m"]), {x, xdummy, Quantity[10, "m"]}]
Plot[result, {xdummy, Quantity[0, "m"], Quantity[10, "m"]}]
```

How can I make this message go away? I would prefer to hint to Mathematica that `xdummy` will be in meters, but I'm willing to use a hack if necessary.

Comment: It probably doesn't know that `xdummy` has units of meters. Why don't you just integrate without the `Quantity`s? It will be faster, it won't throw errors, and you already know what the numbers are anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to wrap `xdummy` in `Quantity`, e.g.

```
result = Integrate[Quantity[3, "kN/m"] (1 - x/Quantity[10, "m"]), 
  {x, Quantity[xdummy,"m"], Quantity[10, "m"]}]
(*
 Quantity[(15000 - 3000 xdummy + 150 xdummy^2), 
  ("Kilograms" "Meters")/("Seconds")^2] 
*)
```

Since `xdummy` is now effectively unitless, you no longer need to include units in `Plot`, e.g.,

```
Plot[result, {xdummy, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm just shaking my head the I wrote "know" when clearly it was "no".  :P

Comment: Perhaps some evil gremlin in your system's auto-correction software? It also just inserted "the" when you clearly meant "that" in your comment.

Comment: damn keyboard gremlins. Need to expose them to sunlight.